# How to properly set getter setter in interface projection for a boolean variable starting with is?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, projection

I am using [interface projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) . For unit testing purpose i have to add both getter and setter. In Jpa query i have a Boolean parameter named `isPublic`. But getter setter not working. i tried following

```
  Boolean isPublic();

  void setPublic(Boolean isPublic);
```

and this

```
  Boolean getIsPublic();

  void setIsPublic(Boolean isPublic);
```

and this

```
  Boolean getPublic();

  void setPublic(Boolean isPublic);
```

But everything works when i change variable name to `public` with setter `setPublic` and getter `getPublic`. How do i properly set getter setter for `isPublic`?

Comment: did you try with generating the getter setter methods through IDE (Yes not in the interface but in some class) ? That should generate the correct one.

Comment: Did you try using Lombok?

Comment: @SKumar they go with `isPublic()` and `setPublic(boolean aPublic)` in class, doesn't work in interface projection

Comment: @mahfujasif Is your parameter is of type boolean or Boolean ? If you got isPublic() from IDE, I suspect that you have parameter of boolean type. isXXX is only boolean types. For rest of the Objects it must be getter/ setter. Another question, can you post your junit test code ?

Comment: @mahfujasif If it of type boolean, did you tried with
    boolean isPublic() and setPublic(boolean aPublic) ?

Comment: @SKumar Its Boolean, already tried isPublic() and setPublic(boolean aPublic) which is mentioned in the question though.

Comment: Can you post the detailed exception from your logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable name is "isPublic", then, your getter should be named isIsPublic.

The "is" shouldn't be in the variable name.

Comment: Not class, interface

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public interface MyClass {
    @Value("#{target.value == 1}")
    Boolean getValue();
}
```